# Timeout not clearing when used in onChange function

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

I'm creating a search function for a website that I'm working on. When a user types in a keyword, a get request will be sent to retrieve the matching information. However, it feels very wasteful to have it fire every time a key is pressed. Say the user wants to search for sandwiches, they will most likely enter that in pretty quick succession I just want to fire it after a certain amount of time after the user stopped typing(say 250ms). My idea is to set a timeout, which will be cleared on a consecutive keystroke. Unfortunately, the timeout does not reset and just ends up being delayed. I tried having it in a useEffect hook, and then the timeout worked fine but I had some other problems which prompted me to try and do it this way.

```
    const onChangeBrand = (e) => {
        const brand = e.target.value
        setBrand(brand)
        const timeout = setTimeout(()=>{
            url.get(`brands?search=${encodeURI(brand.toLowerCase())}&rows=5`)
                .then(res => {
                    setBrands(res.data)
                    if(res.data.length === 1 && res.data[0].urlEncoding === encodeURI(brand.toLowerCase())){
                        setPageType("models")
                    }else{
                        setPageType("brands")
                    }
                })
        },2500)
        return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure simple function works the same as useEffect does. It will not fire on post-render page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea but the wrong execution. Returning a function from an `onChange` handler inherently does nothing–this would have worked fine with `useEffect` so I see where it came from. This pattern is known as [throttling / debouncing](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf) a function and there are tons of premade libraries out there to help you throttle a function (like [lodash.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle)) but it's perfectly cool to spin your own!

The key here would be:

1. Use a timeout variable that is scoped outside the method
2. At the start of execution of your `onChange`, check to see if the timeout variable has a value–if it does, clear it.
3. Execute `onChange`, assign new timeout.

You could use a `ref` or something here but I personally think it's easiest to define your timeout holder outside the scope of your component entirely.

```
let CHANGE_TIMEOUT = null;

function MyComponent(props) {

// .. component code

    const onChangeBrand = (e) => {
        if (CHANGE_TIMEOUT) {
          // we already have a previous timeout, clear it.
          clearTimeout(CHANGE_TIMEOUT);
        }

        const brand = e.target.value
        setBrand(brand)

        // Set the timeout again
        CHANGE_TIMEOUT = setTimeout(()=>{
            url.get(`brands?search=${encodeURI(brand.toLowerCase())}&rows=5`)
                .then(res => {
                    setBrands(res.data)
                    if(res.data.length === 1 && res.data[0].urlEncoding === encodeURI(brand.toLowerCase())){
                        setPageType("models")
                    }else{
                        setPageType("brands")
                    }
                })
        },2500);
      }

// .. other component code here

}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! I have another question, if you don't mind, what would you say an appropriate timeout would be for a function like this? I believe that I read somewhere that 250ms is a good amount, but I would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: In the past I've used `500ms` at the advisement from our UX teams–there's a magic range that keeps the experience snappy, performant, and not like the app is broken.

Comment: Super! Thank ill try that out. Thank you so much for your help!